# QHBoxLayout (size, resize, move)

Tags: python, pyqt5, qwidget

### Task:

For example (the code below) we create QHBoxLayout in which there are two buttons.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QWidget, QPushButton, QHBoxLayout, QApplication)
class Example(QWidget):
    
        def __init__(self):
            super().__init__()
    
            hbox = QHBoxLayout()
            okButton = QPushButton("OK")
            cancelButton = QPushButton("Cancel")
            hbox.addWidget(okButton)
            hbox.addWidget(cancelButton)
            self.setLayout(hbox)
    
            self.setGeometry(100, 100, 500, 500)
            self.show()
    
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
ex = Example()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

### Necessary:

Set the size for **hbox** (QHBoxLayout)  (W_pix, H_pix) and its coordinates (X_pos, Y_pos) on the main window (they do not fit, I did not find such functions in the documentation for the description for QHBoxLayout, QWidget).

v.2

```
import sys

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import QRect
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QWidget, QPushButton,
                             QHBoxLayout, QApplication, QMainWindow, QVBoxLayout)

class Example(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.hbox = QVBoxLayout()
        self.okButton = QPushButton("OK")
        self.cancelButton = QPushButton("Cancel")
        self.hbox.addWidget(self.okButton)
        self.hbox.addWidget(self.cancelButton)

        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 500, 500)
        self.setLayout(self.hbox)
        self.hbox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(200, 200, 300, 300))
        self.show()

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
ex = Example()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Can you show the output screenshot? and explain how exactly the code did not work with the help of the image?

Comment: I can see geometry available for QHBoxLayout https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qboxlayout.html#setGeometry

Comment: Sample code is working.
The question is that you cannot change the size and position. Maybe: hbox.setGeometry(100, 100, 200, 200)? (but didn't work: TypeError: setGeometry(self, QRect): argument 1 has unexpected type 'int')

Comment: The code runs without error like this: hbox.setGeometry (QtCore.QRect (200, 200, 300, 300))
but the sizes QHBoxLayout() do not change.

Comment: Well in the example code you have shown above, there is no window, its a widget. Basically you have set a layout to the widget and you are displaying the widget.
Change the geometry of the widget and put that widget in window. You may get your desired result.

Comment: Changed to: class Example(QMainWindow):
Display gone QVBoxLayout().

Comment: Add new code in the main post (v.2).

Comment: You need a central widget in window to display. That being said when you use a layout qt internally manages the size and position of the button(widgets). This enables proper scaling based on minimizing and maximizing your window.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36844898/pyqt-main-window-vs-dialog

Comment: Further if you are using layouts you need different strategy for positioning and size management.
please read this http://zetcode.com/gui/pyqt5/layout/

Comment: I have read these examples before. But there is a change in the size of the main window, a change in coordinates Labels, Button - there are no problems with this.
But resizing and its position QHBoxLayout - are no examples. This is the problem. I can not find any documentation or examples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A QXLayout is not a visual element, so establishing the geometry (position and size) cannot be applied directly but must be interpreted.

The task of QHBoxLayout is to distribute widgets horizontally using as information the sizeHint, sizePolicy, minimum and maximum sizes, etc. and will use the maximum available size that gives the widget where it was established.

Considering the last point you can extrapolate your requirement to that widget since as described the geometry that handles the layout is that of that widget. So in this case a QWidget used as a container is created.

```py
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QHBoxLayout, QMainWindow, QPushButton, QWidget


class Example(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        x_pos, y_pos = 10, 10
        w_pix, h_pix = 150, 150

        container = QWidget(self)
        container.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        container.setFixedSize(w_pix, h_pix)
        container.move(x_pos, y_pos)
        container.setStyleSheet("background-color:salmon;")

        hbox = QHBoxLayout(container)
        hbox.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)

        self.okButton = QPushButton("OK")
        self.cancelButton = QPushButton("Cancel")

        hbox.addWidget(self.okButton)
        hbox.addWidget(self.cancelButton)

        self.resize(640, 480)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```